# write filename when iterating through dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am passing to a function several pandas `df`:

```
def write_df_to_disk(*args):
    for df in args:
        df.to_csv('/transformed/'+str(df)+'.table',sep='\t')


write_df_to_disk(k562,hepg2,hoel)
```

`df` here will be a pandas dataframe.

How can I assign the diferent parameters of `*args` to a string like above `'/transformed/'+str(df)+'.table',sep='\t'` ??

I want to have three files written to disk with the following path:

```
`/transformed/k562.table`
`/transformed/hepg2.table`
`transformed/hoel.table`
```

Comment: I guess you want the function to know the variable names? This is not possible. You have to transfer the names additionally as strings. Use e. g. a dict like `{'k562': k562,...}` as parameter.

Comment: yeah , not necessarily I just want to write 3 files with the following paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I think I managed.

```
def write_df_to_disk(l,*args):
    for l,df in zip(l,args):
        df.to_csv('transformed/'+l+'.table',sep='\t')

write_df_to_disk(['k562','hepg2','hoel'],k562,hepg2,hoel)
```